# Different ways to choose any two different courses?

Tags: combinatorics

I am self learning mathematics, and have just learned the product principle and addition principle. But I am frustratingly stuck the final question in the following problem.

> A lunchtime menu at a restaurant offers 5 starters, 6 main courses and 3 desserts. How many different choices of meal can you make if you would like

> a) a starter,a main course and a dessert?

Here I use the product principle: $5 \times 6 \times 3 = 90$, which is correct according to the solution.

> b) a main course and either a starter and a dessert?

Here I use a combination of the product and addition principle: $6 \times (5 + 3) = 48$ which is also correct according to the solution.

> b) any two different courses?

Now here I am quite stuck. I initialy read it as two different main courses. Initially I though I could use the product principle again $6 \times 6$, but this does not of course work, since it has to be two different choices. I looked through the chapter, and there is no way to calculate this. I therefore just counted the different sets (1,2) + (1,3) + ... . But when I look at the solution, it says that the correct answer is 63. But no matter how I try to count or think, I am  unsure how I should get to this answer, even if I choose from any of the 14 dishes. Could anyone give me a helping hand?

Comment: The $63$ comes from $(5 \times 6) + (5 \times 3) + (6 \times 3)$.

Comment: An answer of $63$ might make sense if we were to say that a meal we were counting here were exactly "a starter and a main" or "a starter and a dessert" or "a main and a dessert."  Under this interpretation, we would have $5\times 6 + 5\times 3+6\times 3 = 30+15+18=63$.  I will agree that this question is poorly worded

Comment: Ah, I see and that makes totally sense. I did not think about it in that way at all, but I guess you are both right. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I note that my question was downvoted. I tried to ask it as clearly as I could and write my thoughts and what I had tried, and I have tried to look up other sources for an answer, was there anything I could do to write the question better? I know that this is a "homework" question, but since I don't have a teacher I cannot get help from anywhere else but the web. Or should I find a completely other forum to ask questions like this?